# Cross-browser table layout with fixed header and footer

Tags: css, layout

I need help with realisation of the layout below: the header and the footer are sticked to top and to bottom respectively, and the content fills all remained space.

[image: desired layout]

The problem is that heights of header and footer are not specified. I tried to use tables, and that worked, but only in Chrome. And I need it to work in IE8+. Maybe it is simple to modify my attempt?

Here is what I did ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeiA/Xz8Hy/)):

```
<!--HTML-->
<table>
  <tr><td id=header></td></tr>
  <tr><td id=main><div>content</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td id=footer></td></tr>
</table>

/*CSS*/
html, body, table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main{
    height: 100%;
}
#main div{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using position:fixed property header and the footer are sticked to top and to bottom respectively, to adjust content correctly you need to calculate header height**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz8Hy/1/)**

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-color: green;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
#footer {
    background-color: green;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var headerHeight = $("#header").height();

$("#main").css('margin-top' , headerHeight+10);
```

Comment: Well, using JavaScript is the only solution for now to support old browsers, but I still hope the goal can be reached without it as Chrome can handle the table layout.